# If a method is inside a linq query would it be called multiple times?

Tags: c#, performance, linq

If a method is inside a linq query would it be called multiple times? I can't test this because I don't have an IDE. I am learning linq and I use online c# compiler to run the program.

```
var List<Customer> CustomerList = (From c in GetCustomerList()
                                  Where c.Id > 1
                                  Select c).ToList()
```

Would this above code cause performance bottle necks since GetCustomerList method is inside the linq statement?

Comment: Does your online compiler produce output? Throw a Console.Write statement into that method and confirm for yourself. Alternately, download LinqPad (for a quick install) or Visual Studio Community (for the full software suite). Both of which are free.

Comment: I don't know your specific situation, but may I suggest VS express or community edition? It's free... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a decent concern, but you're fine here.

LINQ query syntax is translated to method calls. In your case,

```
var List<Customer> CustomerList = GetCustomerList()
    .Where(c => c.Id > 1)
    .ToList();
```

If you have doubts about it, add a call to `Console.WriteLine` inside `GetCustomerList()`, or take a look over the [source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs) for LINQ.